# Can I clone from a simple file server that has absolutely no Git commands installed?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a NAS setup that has a minimal Linux system installed. I can SSH to it, but I haven't had any luck installing a package manager and subsequently software like GCC or Git, so it is an extremely bare bones system right now.

I have copied a small Git repository to a directory of the NAS via SFTP, and I'm trying to clone it, but I've had no success. I've tried multiple variations of the path, but I always get this error:

```
sh: git-upload-pack: not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm confused about what it means. The [`git-upload-pack` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack/2.19.2) says:

> Invoked by *git fetch-pack*, learns what objects the other side is missing, and sends them after packing.

The command exists on my client computer.

Is `git upload-pack` invoked on the server? Does this mean I need to have Git (or parts of it) installed on both sides in order for Git SSH access to work? Or am I misdiagnosing and probably just getting the path wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need git installed on the server (here, your NAS). If the system is not able to support it, you're to find another solution to achieve whaetever goal you aimed for with this setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I clone from a simple file server that has absolutely no Git commands installed?

No.
Which means you need an alternative solution, like compressing your Git repository/working tree as an archive, stpf that archive file, and uncompress it on the other side.
From there, you would be able to access your repos files, even though its history would still remain non-usable, since you have no Git installed.

Comment: I managed to force an installation of Git into the NAS and now I can indeed perform operations on repositories inside of it. That was a fun afternoon!